# Android 6 - Location permissions and map display

Tags: android

I have implemented code to request for accessing location and that seems to be working fine. When the app is started for the very first time, it is showing a dialog box asking whether to allow access to the location or not.

Once the access is granted, how is it possible to zoom to the current location? I have tried to restart the activity, but that does not help and all I get is the whole world map.

If I exit the app and start, it works as expected. Is there a way to overcome this behaviour?

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case LOCATION_REQUEST:
                if (canAccessLocation()) {
                    //Tried to restart activity here 
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Cannot access location");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

here is the part from onCreate where the map is zoomed into (in the method plotLocationOnMap)...

```
if (canAccessLocation()) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                LatLng pos = position.target;

                double distance = LineStation.getDistance(lastLat, lastLong, pos.latitude, pos.longitude);
                if (distance < 0.3) {
                    return;
            }

            lastLat = pos.latitude;
            lastLong = pos.longitude;

            plotLocationOnMap(pos.latitude, pos.longitude);
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new RemindTask(pos.latitude, pos.longitude), 1000);
           }
        });

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

        double latitude = 0;
        double longitude = 0;
        Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
        if (myLocation != null) {
            plotLocationOnMap(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
        } else {
            GPSTracker gpst = new GPSTracker(context);
            latitude = gpst.getLatitude();
            longitude = gpst.getLongitude();

            plotLocationOnMap(latitude, longitude);
        }
    }
} else {
   requestPermissions(LOCATION_PERMS, LOCATION_REQUEST);
}

private void plotLocationOnMap(double latitude, double longitude) {
        mMap.clear();
        Marker m1;

        String address = getAddress(latitude, longitude);

        m1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.flag))
                .title(address));
        m1.showInfoWindow();

        final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(m1.getPosition());

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))        // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                .zoom(ZOOM)                                     // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(0)                                     // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(45)                                       // Sets the tilt of the camera to 45 degrees
                .build();                                       // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
```

Comment: is your 'zooming' code implemented ? are you using google maps or something else ?

Comment: I am using google maps and the zooming code is implemented. It works fine if I grant the access to location, exit the app and start it again.

I just want this to happen after I grant the access to location, without exiting the app.

Comment: just wrap that code into a method and call it when you need

Comment: Ok, so in the place where I am trying to restart activity, I just run the code... I will try doing that. Thanks.

Comment: I have added further code where the zooming takes place. On debugging, I can see that the code is being executed, however, on the actual device I don't see the zoomed in map.

Answer (score -2):

> Once the access is granted, how is it possible to zoom to the current location?

Do not take confusion to us.

You need to understand that this is a two different process.
Asking for permissions - is a security issue only, and zoom - is a responsibility of GoogleMap implementation. So there is no clear to me why you need restart your activity. You need actually initialize map **ONLY** after user allow use LOCATION_SERVICES in your app. Not before.

To get in touch of zoom map look at the [Camera and View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views) sample.